# How to know if javascript array object values are true?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a simple array of objects.

```
  { id: 1, name: 'John', license: true },
  { id: 1, name: 'Sam', license: false },
  { id: 1, name: 'Luis', license: true }
];
```

How to make a reusable function to check:
1) if license property for all of them together is true
2) if one of license property is true

Comment: [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Hone those problem solving skills by giving it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with these:

```js
const data = [{ id: 1, name: 'John', license: true },
  { id: 1, name: 'Sam', license: false },
  { id: 1, name: 'Luis', license: true }
];

var allTrue = data.every(i=> i.license === true);
console.log(allTrue);

var someTrue = data.some(k=> k.license === true)
console.log(someTrue)
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps

```js
 var array = [{ id: 1, name: 'John', license: true },
  { id: 1, name: 'Sam', license: false},
  { id: 1, name: 'Luis', license: true }
];

var trueCounter = 0;

function checkValid(arr){
 for(let obj of arr){
  if(obj.license == true){
   trueCounter++;
  } 
 }
 if(trueCounter == array.length){
   return "all items are true"
  } else if (trueCounter >= 1){
   return "at least one item is true"
  } else {
   return "all items are false"
  }
}

console.log(checkValid(array));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I was looking for

Comment: Im glad my code helps you!, maybe a thumbs up? thanks